# gdb print and examine commands give incorrect results for a float variable

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, nasm, dwarf

I'm going through a book on x64 assembly. The book described a little on how to use gdb I was able to examine integers however print wouldn't work.
examine would work for integers if I included the size such as "db" by using examine like so,
`x/bu &bNum` which would output 123 as expected.

for a float value though if I did not examine an integer before examining a float, I would get what I believe is an incorrect result.
running `x/qf &qNum3` would output the result 1.26443839e+11

if I used `x/bu &bNum` then ran `x/qf &qNum3`
it would give the expected result 3.1400000000000001
So why does examining a float give the correct output only after examining an integer?

using any of the previous commands without the ampersand '&' resulted in gdb responding with
" 'qNum3' has unknown type; cast it to it's declared type "
is this the expected response?

print just doesn't seem to ever give the right result.

I'm using the commands bellow, as the book instructed, in order to assemble and link the program
`nasm -f elf64 -g -F dwarf move.asm -l move.lst`
`gcc -o move move.o -no-pie`

This is an example program given by the book.

```
; move.asm
section .data
      bNum  db    123
      wNum  dw    12345
      dNum  dd    1234567890
      qNum1 dq    1234567890123456789
      qNum2 dq    123456
      qNum3 dq    3.14
section .bss
section .text
      global main
main:
push  rbp
mov   rbp,rsp
      mov rax, -1           ; fill rax with 1s
      mov al, byte [bNum]   ; does NOT clear upper bits of rax
      xor rax,rax           ; clear rax
      mov al, byte [bNum]   ; now rax has the correct value
      mov rax, -1           ; fill rax with 1s
      mov ax, word [wNum]   ; does NOT clear upper bits of rax
      xor rax,rax           ; clear rax
      mov ax, word [wNum]   ; now rax has the correct value
      mov rax, -1           ; fill rax with 1s
      mov eax, dword [dNum] ; does clear upper bits of rax
      mov rax, -1           ; fill rax with 1s
      mov rax, qword [qNum1] ; does clear upper bits of rax
      mov qword [qNum2], rax ; one operand always a register
      mov rax, 123456       ; source operand an immediate value
      movq xmm0, [qNum3]    ; instruction for floating point
mov rsp,rbp
pop rbp
ret
```

`x/qf &qNum3` expected something close to 3.14
`x/qf &qNum3` would output the result "<0x404027> 1.26443839e+11"

`x/qt &qNum3` expected something close to 01000000 01001000 11110101 11000011
`x/qt &qNum3` would output the result     01010001 11101011 10000101 00011111

`x/qx &qNum3` expected something close to 0x4048F5C3
`x/qx &qNum3` would output the result     0x51eb851f

`print /f &qNum3`expected something close to 3.14
`print /f &qNum3` would output "$2 = 2.0803755547161745e-317"

If the command `x/bu &bNum` was run first the previous examine commands would now output results different than before.

the command `x/qf &qNum3` would output the expected result 3.14

`x/qt &qNum3` would now output the result     00011111

`x/qx &qNum3` would now output the result     0x1f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/q` isn't a size modifier for GDB.  According to `h x`, 8-byte size is `/g` (Giant).

**`x /gf &qNum3` correctly eXamines memory as 8-byte doubles,**
as does `p (double)qNum3`.  `print /f &qNum3` interprets the address as a float bit-pattern, same result as `print (double)&qNum3`, a tiny subnormal float (only some bits set near the bottom of the mantissa).

GDB casts use C syntax but they're like std::bit_cast to tell it how to interpret the bits, not to produce a new value in a different type that represents the same number.  (At least for variables, not for constants like `print (double)1234`.)

---

I don't know what `/q` does as a modifier for /x, but with the size still being the default 32-bit, you're interpreting the low 4 bytes of the mantissa as a `float` (IEEE binary32), the same number you get from `p (float)qNum3`

(`x` remembers the last size you used, so if you had used an 8-byte-chunk `x` previously, `x /f` would work, too.  And that's why `x /b` (Byte) changes results from later `x` commands that don't include a size.)

You can also do `p (double[3])qNum1` to interpret all 3 qwords as IEEE binary64 bit-patterns.  (The first two are integers in the NASM source whose bit-patterns represent tiny doubles.)

Comment: Ah thanks. I was still thinking in terms of assembly sizes like dq and assumed q would be a size specifier. I wasn't keeping in mind that gdb probably wouldn't be catering to x64 assembly programs.

Comment: @user17917376: I thought you might be.  `d` and `l` (Intel/AT&T 32-bit) aren't GDB size modifiers either, and `w`ord in GDB means 32-bit vs. 16-bit in x86.    The only size that matches is `b`yte.  So that's something you always have to keep in mind with GDB size specifiers for the `x` command.  I find `p`rint and `d`isplay (print after every single step) are nice, including its array syntax watching some memory change as I single-step.

Comment: _side note:_ Peter, you are needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77399491/5382650 :-)

Comment: `/q` does nothing. You can see this if you just try `x/q` without any other format modifiers: `Undefined output format "q".` It just uses the last lowercase character, which isn't a size modifier, as the format modifier.

Comment: @ssbssa: Huh, I expected there to be more input validation to reject invalid format characters instead of silently ignoring in some cases.  Thanks for checking on that.