# Contention for stores to a shared cache line from all cores on multiple sockets (Xeon Scalable) is causing system to become sluggish

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, cpu-architecture, numa

```
#include <glibmm/thread.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void threadLoop(int *PtrCounter)
{

    struct timespec sleep = {0};

    while (1)
    {
        *PtrCounter += 1; // #1: commenting this fixes the slow responsiveness
        //clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, 0, &sleep, NULL); // #2 uncommenting this fixes the slow responsiveness
        // sched_yield(); // #3 uncommenting this does nothing (still get slow responsiveness)
    }
}

int counter = 0;

void ExitHandler(int signum)
{
    printf("counter=%d\n", counter);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numThreads = get_nprocs();
    int i;

    printf("using %d threads... (Ctrl-C to stop)\n", numThreads);

    signal(SIGINT, ExitHandler);

    Glib::Thread *threadArray[numThreads];

    for (i=0; i<numThreads; i++)
    {
        threadArray[i] = Glib::Thread::create(std::bind(&threadLoop, &counter));
    }

    // never returns
    for (i=0; i<numThreads; i++)
    {
        threadArray[i]->join();
    }
}
```

compiled without optimization so the asm does what the source says (load and store `counter` from every thread):

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags glibmm-2.4` threads.cpp
```

I'm running this code on Fedora 38, kernel 6.5.8-200 on a Dell PowerEdge R760 (Xeon Platinum 8480+, 256G memory, get_nprocs() returns 224)

When I run this code, the system becomes horribly unresponsive (slow to respond to mouse clicks and keyboard presses).  Navigating around in firefox become unbearably slow.  Why is this happening?

Your first reaction may be that this is horrible code because *PtrCounter is not protected by any sort of syncronization and you are correct.  I originally was using __atomic_add_fetch() to do the increment and I saw the same slow responsiveness.  Trying to get to the minimal reproducible example, I removed the atomic stuff.  So yes, it will count incorrectly but I think this helps demonstrate the issue.

Your next reaction is probably, "Of course you are going to get some sluggishness, you are hogging the CPU".  Yes, I'm hogging the cpu, but that in itself does not cause this sluggishness.  As "#1" in the comments says, if I comment out the "*PtrCounter +=1" the sluggishness goes away and in that case I am still hogging the cpu just as much (as seen from top).

The other thing is if I run this code on other systems (a much older 8-cpu intel, or a newer 128-cpu amd), I do not get the sluggishness.  I invite you to try the code on your system.  Unless, it is a newer high cpu count intel, I bet it works just fine and you won't experience sluggishness.

You can see the #2 and #3 comments in the code.  Not sure what to make of it but I thought it was interesting enough to mention.

So what is at the root of this sluggishness?  I get that having lots of contention is bad causing lots of cache thrashing and can reduce the performance of your algorithm, but I don't believe it should impact the responsiveness of the OS.  Shouldn't the OS force involuntary context switches and handle interrupts just as fast whether those algorithms are hitting contention or not?

Comment: `int counter = 0;` is being modified on multiple threads with no synchronisation. Does not explain the sluggishness, but puts the code into UB land.

Comment: You have three different Undefined Behaviours at place. If you comment out incrementing, you get down to one (but that's exactly as bad). Any reasoning would be based purely on compiler implementation, after seeing what it decided to do with this code.

Comment: Re: “it will count incorrectly” — maybe. Or anything else. The behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: *I removed the atomic stuff* Avoid doing that. People will lock onto the low-hanging fruit and ignore the problem you really want solved. In general, keep the example small, but as close to the original as possible, and if you inject new bugs... You'll get answers dealing with the new bugs, so don't do anything you know is wrong/stupid to simplify the example.

Comment: Thread sync doesn't matter. Your thread functions are infinite loops. Of course you are going to max out all cpus

Comment: `get_nprocs() returns 224` how many cores do you have?

Comment: With `*PtrCounter +=1` you are incrementing the same memory location. On x86 it has a tight memory model. The cpus are cache snooping and bouncing the data between the L1 per cpu caches. You are memory bus bound and swamping the memory controller. It can probably handle only a relatively few threads before it becomes the bottleneck. Even without atomics, there is a lot of serialization going on. Start with 1 thread and gradually increase the number of threads. You will probably get rolloff after 8 threads or so

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes I believe it has something to do with this.  When I reduced it down to nproc/4 the sluggishness went away.  It did not with nproc/2.  

This server has 4 cpus each with 56 cores.

Comment: How much memory? Check paging disk activity and cumulative resident set size (RSS). Even after you stop your program, I bet it takes 20 minutes to get `firefox` back to normal (you've stolen its pages and it's a pig and has to page its data back in). I've long suspected that linux's paging algorithm is suboptimal in these situations.

Comment: @CraigEstey The system has 256G of memory and firefox gets back to normal instantly.  My program actually uses very little memory, it is just that all the threads are using the same cache line.

Getting back to the "memory bus bound" statement.  I believe L3 is coherent with all the cores, so I think we aren't actually going to memory but just L3 so we would be staying in the intel UPI world.  So we are perhaps maxing out UPI which would be impressive. 

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/231746/intel-xeon-platinum-8480-processor-105m-cache-2-00-ghz/specifications.html

Comment: oh, cool it looks like there is code to monitor UPI performance.  I'll take a look at this tomorrow when I have access to the system again.  https://github.com/intel/pcm

Comment: @CraigEstey: Not the *memory* controllers; coherency traffic over the mesh network will be between cores and the L3 slice holding the global `int counter;` that all cores are loading from and storing to.  Its ownership will bounce between cores, but it doesn't have to get written back to DRAM, only to L3.  I think the OP's right to suspect the UPI links between cores being a limit, or a queue of Read-For-Ownership requests at that one L3 slice (HW arbitration for ownership), or snoop filters for traffic between sockets, or something like that.

Comment: A useful experiment would be pinning the threads to the cores of one socket (NUMA domain) with `taskset -c 0-55 ./a.out` or something.  NUMA placement should hopefully mean the page of BSS holding the counter is in local DRAM for all those cores, so all the coherency traffic stays within the package, with snoop filters at UPI socket boundaries meaning that other sockets aren't being bothered (unlike on Broadwell and earlier E5 Xeons, which I think just broadcast snoops to the other socket, which scaled well enough with a max of 2 sockets, unlike E7 Xeons which had snoop filters.)

Comment: You could get basically the same asm as a debug build of `*PtrCounter += 1;` by using `std::atomic` to avoid data-race and integer overflow UB.  `counter.store( counter.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) + 1, std::memory_order_relaxed);`.  That will also let you compile with optimization without optimizing away the memory access from the loop, but still using plain stores like `mov` or `add [mem], 1` instead of `lock add [mem], 1`.

Comment: Note that mouse clicks and anything else with an X11 (or Wayland?) GUI involves inter-process communication between the X server and clients such as Firefox.  And de-allocating memory often involves the kernel which may have to do TLB shootdowns via Inter-Processor-Interrupts.  So your test program that clogs up inter-core communication links with RFO requests could plausibly slow that down a lot.  It's not just about handling interrupts within one core.

Comment: I thought for a second maybe draining the store buffer after an interrupt happens could be slow, too, but that wouldn't happen with `atomic<int>` increments on x86-64; each `lock add` drains the store buffer.

Comment: @CraigEstey: All mainstream CPU ISAs use some form of MESI coherency where a core has to get exclusive ownership of a line before committing a store (to modify the line in L1d cache).  The storm of coherency traffic across every core isn't unique to x86's strongly-ordered memory model, although different microarchitectures use different interconnect designs and different snoop-filters and stuff.

Comment: @PeterCordes  "taskset -c 0-55 ./a.out" does in-fact take away the sluggishness.

Comment: I tried the pcm utility and it looks like the UPI bandwidth is not affected at all when I run the test.  Even if I don't understand the precise root cause, maybe it is enough to say you just can't hammer on the same piece of memory with all the cores.  It's just unfortunate that you used to be able to get away with this on previous hardware.

Comment: Have you tried it on older multi-socket Xeon systems?  As you showed with `taskset -c 0-55`, you still can on a single-socket Ice Lake Xeon.  And I'd assume it's also fine with all cores of any "client" CPU (like Alder Lake), since they're limited to single-socket and still use a ring bus, not mesh.  Or wait, when you said "a much older 8-cpu intel", did you mean 8-socket, rather than 8-core single-socket?